# How to get rid of 'more...' button in tab bar app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

ive searched for 2 weeks solid on this and cant find an answer. ive posted on a couple of other sdk forums and nobody seems to have a clue...

i am building a tab bar app and i want to have 6 pages with 6 icons on the tab bar at the bottom. by default if you add more than 4 icons to the tab bar, when you build the app you get the 'more...' button. i dont want that.

everyone tells me its not possible, but obviously it IS possible because there are a number of apps with 6 icons in the tab bar.

the free app 'college football live!' for instance, has 6 icons in the tab bar

screenshot of the app
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYyTC.png

the only thing ive been able to find is this piece of code for a tutorial here...

raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-uitabbarcontroller-how-to-save-user-customized-tab-order/

im not sure if that code can be changed to create 6 icons or not, but if anyone can help me out with this i would really appreciate it.

Comment: Check at the last paragraphs on this page: http://praxisstalled.blogspot.com/2010/08/customising-appearance-of.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the most easy way do to this is to create your own tab bar.

Answer (score 1):

on screen only 5 tab can see possible if you want to implement more button there is two ways to do this thing first is use toolbar instead of tabbar controller and other is use button at bottom to show it like tabbar